# Can I use 2 x QID-E128LPAF on 2 PCIe x16 and get 8 independent displays?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I currently have 2 PCs that have Matrox QID-E128LPAF graphics inside and this gives me 4 displays each. I want to buy a new motherboard with 2 PCIe x16 slots, plug it there and have 8 displays. Will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Matrox's [QID LP PCIe product page](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/legacy/qid_series/qidlppcie/):

> The Matrox QID LP PCIe is a multi monitor PCI express x16 graphics
>   card that fits in low-profile and ATX systems. It supports up to four
>   digital or analog monitors at independent or stretched resolutions.
>   **Install another Matrox quad monitor graphics card to your system and
>   drive up to eight monitors simultaneously**–enabling you to see more and
>   do more.

Comment: I found this one and wonder if someone tried this. But this is an answer to my question, so thank you :)